Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{n x^2}{1+2 n+x}$

Study uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on the set $E$ :
$$f_n(x)=\frac{n x^2}{1+2 n+x}, \quad E=[1,+\infty)$$

I found that it converges pointwise to $\frac{x^2}{2}$
\begin{align*}
\left| f_n(x) - \frac{x^2}{2} \right| &= \left| \frac{n x^2}{1 + 2 n + x} - \frac{x^2}{2} \right| \\
&= x^2 \left| \frac{n}{1 + 2 n + x} - \frac{1}{2} \right| \\
&= x^2 \left| \frac{2 n - (1 + 2 n + x)}{2 (1 + 2 n + x)} \right| \\
&= x^2 \left| \frac{- (1 + x)}{2 (1 + 2 n + x)} \right| \\
&= \frac{x^2 (1 + x)}{2 (1 + 2 n + x)}
\end{align*}
The numerator grows like
$x^3$
while the denominator grows like
$x$, so the whole tends to infinity. Hence it doesn't converges uniformly.
Am I right? Because in class I was supposed to prove that $f_n(x)=\frac{n x^2}{n+x}$ on $E=[1,+\infty)$ converges uniformly. Was it a mistake? Does this also not converge uniformly?

Note that, for pointwise convergence, you're supposed to check the limit as $n \to \infty$. Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{x^2 (1 + x)}{2 (1 + 2 n + x)}
= 0
$$
for every fixed $x$, you have pointwise convergence.

For uniform convergence, an equivalence is
$$
f_n \xrightarrow[\text{uniformly}]{n \to +\infty} f
\iff
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0
$$
For this you would look at the difference you already calculated between the sequence and limit,
$$
\frac{x^2 (1 + x)}{2 (1 + 2 n + x)}
$$
Notice that, for any fixed $n$, taking $x$ sufficiently large will always ensure the supremum is greater than, say, $1$, so the limit is not zero and hence convergence is not uniform.
I'll let you fill in the details there.

Both $\frac{nx^2}{1+2n+x}$ and $\frac{nx^2}{n+x}$ are not converges uniformly on $E=[1, \infty)$.
For $f(x) = \frac{nx^2}{1+2n+x}$, Consider the sequence $x_n = 2n+1$.
From your calculations, we have
$$ \left|f_n(x_n)- \frac{{x_n}^2}{2}\right| = \frac{{x_n} ^2 (1+x_n)}{2(1+2n+x_n)} = \frac{(2n+1)^2 (2n+2) }{2(4n+2)} = \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2} $$
Hence, For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, You may found some $x_n$ that the difference between $f_n(x_n)$ and $\frac{{x_n}^2}{2}$ is not small enough.
